# Having blue background when clicking on sidebar toggle

Tags: html, css, angular

I am following the tutorials of https://github.com/daniel-koti/responsive-dashboard
when i opened the files directly it worked like charm , when using it inside angular project and included it worked but with blue background when sliding the sidebar as showen in the screen shot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEgRW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should inspect the blue part (html & css) with your browser to find where the issue is coming from.

Also, you're not sharing your code, we can't help more